# autoconf detecting where pthread functions really are

Tags: pthreads, autoconf, libc

I'm looking for a way to detect where pthread functions really exist (libc, libpthread or both). My motivation is that GNU libc seems to be moving the pthread functions from libpthread to libc. I need to intercept these functions and to determine which library to intercept at configure time. To complicate the supported platforms are Linux glibc, Solaris, FreeBSD, macOS and Linux musl, with the emphasis on Linux glibc.

I don't think that AC_CHECK_LIB and AC_SEARCH_LIBS are suitable, they will just try to compile a little stub containing the function and linking with the library. Since libc gets linked by default this won't work.

So far I've come up with something like this

```
  safe_CFLAGS=$CFLAGS
  CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -nodefaultlibs -lc"
  AC_MSG_CHECKING([if pthread_cond_destroy is in libc])
  AC_LINK_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[]], [[
      #include <pthread.h>
      (void)pthread_cond_destroy(0);
  ]])], [
  PTHREAD_IN_LIBC=1
  AC_MSG_RESULT([yes])
  ], [
  AC_MSG_RESULT([no])
  ])
  CFLAGS=$safe_CFLAGS
```

This seems to work OK-ish for detecting if functions are in libc (and perhaps AC_SEARCH_LIBS could do the same more easily).

But for checking libpthread I get

```
configure:16532: clang -o conftest  -nodefaultlibs -lpthread  
conftest.c  >&5 ld: error: undefined symbol: atexit
>>> referenced by crt1.c:63 (/usr/src/lib/csu/amd64/crt1.c:63)
```

(plus similar errors for `_init_tls` and `exit`)

Plan B to use `nm` but that seems *really* brittle - libs may be stripped, and I'd have to handle every different path / library name.

UPDATE:

I've made some progress.

```
ac_pthread_create_in_libc=yes
ac_pthread_cond_destroy_in_libc=yes
ac_sem_open_in_libc=yes

AC_SEARCH_LIBS([pthread_create], , , [ac_pthread_create_in_libc=no],)
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([pthread_cond_destroy], , , [ac_pthread_cond_destroy_in_libc=no],)
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([sem_open], , , [ac_sem_open_in_libc=no],)

ac_thread_fns_only_in_libc=no

if test x$ac_pthread_create_in_libc = xyes \
        -a x$ac_pthread_cond_destroy_in_libc = xyes \
        -a x$ac_sem_open_in_libc = xyes ; then
  ac_thread_fns_only_in_libc=yes
fi

ac_thread_fns_only_in_libpthread=no

if test x$ac_thread_fns_only_in_libc = xno ; then

  ac_pthread_create_in_libpthread=no
  ac_pthread_cond_destroy_in_libpthread=no
  ac_sem_open_in_libpthread=no
  
  if test x$ac_pthread_create_in_libc = xno ; then
    unset ac_cv_search_pthread_create
    safe_LIBS=$LIBS
    AC_SEARCH_LIBS([pthread_create], [pthread], [ac_pthread_create_in_libpthread=yes], ,)
    LIBS=$safe_LIBS
  fi

  if test x$ac_pthread_cond_destroy_in_libc = xno ; then
    unset ac_cv_search_pthread_cond_destroy
    AC_SEARCH_LIBS([pthread_cond_destroy], [pthread], [ac_pthread_cond_destroy_in_libc=yes], ,)
    LIBS=$safe_LIBS
  fi
    
  if test x$ac_sem_open_in_libc= xyes ; then
    unset ac_cv_search_sem_open
    AC_SEARCH_LIBS([sem_open], [pthread], [ac_sem_open_in_libc=yes], ,)
    LIBS=$safe_LIBS
  fi
  
  if test x$ac_pthread_create_in_libpthread = xyes \
          -a x$ac_pthread_cond_destroy_in_libpthread = xyes \
          -a x$ac_sem_open_in_libpthread = xyes ; then
    ac_thread_fns_only_in_libpthread=yes
  fi
fi

ac_thread_fns_in_libc_and_libpthread=no
if test x$ac_thread_fns_only_in_libc = xno -a \
        x$ac_thread_fns_only_in_libpthread = xno ; then
  ac_thread_fns_in_libc_and_libpthread=yes
fi

AC_MSG_NOTICE([libc $ac_thread_fns_only_in_libc pthread $ac_thread_fns_only_in_libpthread both $ac_thread_fns_in_libc_and_libpthread])
```

This seems to work. I'll make it an answer when it's production ready.

Comment: I'm not following why you think `AC_SEARCH_LIBS` won't do everything you want. That libc is linked by default is not an issue, I think, because `AC_SEARCH_LIBS` tries first to link without any of the specified libraries, and that will catch the case of pthreads functions being in libc.

Comment: But you may have a larger problem here: on a given system, different versions of the pthreads functions may be present in different libraries.  For instance, there may be do-nothing stubs in libc and fully-functional versions in libpthread.  If you have to contend with such cases then "which library contains the pthread functions?" is probably the wrong question.

Comment: @John Bollinger The problem that I see with `AC_SEARCH_LIBS` is that it will be able to tell me that a functiion is in libc (or even neither lib), but not that it is in both libc and libpthread. I will do some testing and update the question.

Comment: Ok, I see now.  But the bottom line is that you cannot expect to successfully link much of anything without including libc in the link, except code designed for a standalone environment (kernels, boot loaders, ...). and that definitely does not include libpthread or pretty much any other distributed library.

Comment: You could use [`ax_pthread`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_pthread.html) from the autoconf archive. You can include the m4 macro with your package. It's quite comprehensive, and might save you a lot of work. These macros have typically been tested extensively on a variety of platforms.